# How to hold up drawing of a UI element until rest of the page has loaded?

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

ListView is making the startup time of my app very long. First I see nothing and then the whole page with all of it's contents is drawn at once. How can I make the page draw up without the ListView (or an indeterminate progress ring at it's place) and only after that start drawing the ListView? Also the app need to be able to respond to a backey press during loading. Changing ListView.Visibility to collapsed at XAML and the to Visible on Page_Loaded does not have the desired effect; Only if I leave the ListView collapsed then do I get a fast pageload.

PS: I think virtualization is not the issue here: As 17 items of the list are visible at any time; The list is virtualized but it does load 52 items of the total 68 on startup; But then again the list is not that long.

[image]

Comment: I doubt the drawing (rendering) of your ListView is slow. It's more likely that there is some bitmap or other data being loaded for that `ListView` that slows things down. Anyways - it might be hard to guess what the reason is without looking at all the code or at least knowing what you are trying to display in the `ListView`. You can try to share some more of it or just running your app through a profiler to see where the time is spent - especially on the UI/dispatcher thread.

Comment: @Filip No images, just text on my list.

Comment: Well, with 2s spent in 53 ListViewItems - there must be something wrong in there. I'd dig into that branch in the profiler. Maybe all that text is a book-full of text per item? :)

Comment: Six bindings per list item or row though, but I need them to be able to update them dynamicically.

Comment: Consider not using bindings to see if that helps. I've heard of bindings being potentially slow and although 53 items is not so much - 6 bindings per item does sound like too much. See if you could limit that number. You can also not use bindings at all. You can use `DataContextChanged` event in the item view and on that event sync the values from the model and the view. You can also subclass the `ListView` and override `PrepareContainerForItemOverride` Maybe you don't need all of them until your item gets selected? Also make sure whatever view model properties your bindings access isn't slow.

Comment: Have you ever wondered why everybody using XAML based technologies is able to get their code working and using proper DataBinding except yourself? Please post the relevant code and XAML if you expect to get relevant answers here. BTW, NO, manually creating UI elements in procedural code like winforms is NOT the answer.