# How to populate a ListView with groups in a NON MVVM FASHION?

Tags: wpf, windows-runtime

In XAML I have:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView1" />
```

In code behind I have:

```
Private Sub BuildList()
    For i As Integer = 1 To 5
        Dim a1 As New Border With {.Background = New SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.DarkOrange), .Padding = New Thickness(5, 15, 5, 15), .Margin = New Thickness(0, 0, 0, 10)}
        Dim b1 As New TextBlock With {.Text = i, .FontSize = 30, .TextLineBounds = TextLineBounds.Tight}
        a1.Child = b1
        Dim c1 As New GroupItem With {.Content = a1}
        ListView1.Items.Add(c1)
        For j As Integer = 1 To 5
            Dim a2 As New Border With {.Background = New SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.DarkOliveGreen), .Padding = New Thickness(20, 10, 0, 10), .Margin = New Thickness(0, 0, 0, 10)}
            Dim b2 As New TextBlock With {.Text = i, .FontSize = 20, .TextLineBounds = TextLineBounds.Tight}
            a2.Child = b2
            ListView1.Items.Add(a2)
        Next
    Next
    Debug.WriteLine(ListView1.IsGrouping.ToString)
End Sub
```

Sadly IsGrouping returns false and the headers won't stick at the top as they should when scrolling.

PS: Please no preaching about how one should be binding to a CollectionViewsource.

Comment: delete all that and use proper DataBinding. WPF does not care what you think, it's not intended to be used like winforms. Learn to use WPF properly. If you don't like / don't understand how WPF works, then you're free to choose other technologies.

Comment: See [ListView grouping](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-grouping/).

Comment: @Sheridan I think we have an interesting challenge here. If you look at some of the OP's previous question, he's having performance issues with a ListView with less than 100 items. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24455514/how-to-hold-up-drawing-of-a-ui-element-until-rest-of-the-page-has-loaded). I think that's why the OP decided to go this route in the first place.

Comment: @HighCore: Indeed performance and also memory issues are the reason.         Only I target Windows Phone so there aren't alternative technologies. Besides I code as a hobby not as a business. Anyways it seems like sticky headers on the listview are baked in the databindings; Please tell if I'm wrong. If my hunch is right though it seems like building custom sticky headers functionality from the basic UI elements would be the way to achieve the most light weight solution. Infact I have a rough version in the making already.